# Accessing TempData in Middleware in a asp.net 5.0 web api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, middleware, tempdata

I have two applications running together at the same time. I was trying to find a way to be able to use `TempData` in my own type of class and after reading it I implemented it in my Middleware for my MVC project which works smoothly. However, when I copy the Middleware code from my MVC project to my Middleware for my asp.net web api project it does not work. When I run the programs together, and when it calls the web api project it returns the following the web api (MVC works fine I do not get any errors on that):

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataDictionaryFactory' while attempting to activate 'AddressService.API.Middleware.CorrelationIdMiddleware'.

[image]

Before I implemented TempData (`ITempDataDictionaryFactory`) in the middleware of my web api project it worked fine... but after implementing `ITempDataDictionaryFactory` to it, it gives me that error. Is there something I have to do in order for it to work like it does in my Middleware for my MVC project?

`Middleware` in my web api project:

```
    public class CorrelationIdMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDataDictionaryFactory;
        public CorrelationIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<CorrelationIdMiddleware>();
            _tempDataDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionaryFactory;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            string correlationId = null;
            string userName;
            string ipAddress;

            var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(context);

            var key = context.Request.Headers.Keys.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ToLower().Equals("x-correlation-id"));
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
            {
                correlationId = context.Request.Headers[key];
                _logger.LogInformation("Header contained CorrelationId: {@CorrelationId}", correlationId);
            }
            else
            {
                if (tempData.ContainsKey("username") && tempData.ContainsKey("ipaddress"))
                {
                    userName = tempData.Peek("username").ToString();

                    ipAddress = tempData.Peek("ipaddress").ToString();

                    context.Response.Headers.Append("X-username", userName);
                    context.Response.Headers.Append("X-ipAddress", ipAddress);
                }

                correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                _logger.LogInformation("Generated new CorrelationId: {@CorrelationId}", correlationId);
            }
            context.Response.Headers.Append("x-correlation-id", correlationId);
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", correlationId))
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }
```

`CorrelationIdExtensions.cs` (use to call `app.UseCorrelationId()` in startup):

```
public static class CorrelationIdExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCorrelationId(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CorrelationIdMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "AddressService.API", Version = "v1" });
            });

           services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCorrelationId();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "AddressService.API v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to solve this should be using:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

or

```
services.AddMvc();
```

Instead of `services.AddControllers();`.

Comment: I tried it with the first method and it worked! Thank you!